# Https for Aruba domain hosted on google cloud platform

Tags: ssl, https, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, aruba

Hi I have a domain on aruba, hosting is an instance of compute engine on google cloud platform.

I managed to point the domain to hosting by setting two A records from Aruba in DNS management

RECORD A

[empty] IPADDRESS

[www] IPADDRESS

At this point how do I activate https for the domain in question?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this and enable HTTPS for your website, would be using [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) which is a free, automated and open [Certificate Authority (CA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority). Through their website, you can navigate to the documentation where explains how it works, how to use it and provides useful information.

But probably StackOverflow is not the best place to ask this question. It's better to ask in the ServerFault site since it's a server and not coding problem.